# Attempt to read property "nama" on int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

im trying to get the latest data on database, im using this on my views :

```
@foreach ($shows as $s)
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{$loop->iteration}}</th>
              <td>{{$s->nama}}</td>
              <td>{{$s->umur}}</td>
              <td>{{$s->alamat}}</td>
              <td>{{$s->nama_ortu}}</td>
              <td>{{$s->posyandu}}</td>
              <td>{{$s->result}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          @endforeach
```

and on controller :

```
public function showresultpasien()
{
    $shows = DB::table('pasiens')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    return view('result', compact('shows'));
}
```

did i doin something wrong ?

Comment: You're only reading a single row from your database, so don't `foreach` over it.

Comment: aah, how stupid i am. thanks for answering, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function in the model cannot be the same as the name of a field in your table. Also in my case the column names do not follow the laravel/eloquent nomenclature so another parameter is added to belongsTo with the field name